# Linking to sibling libtool library with recursive Automake

Tags: shared-libraries, autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

I am building a shared library, and have a source tree structured like this:

```
Makefile.am
src/
    Makefile.am
    srcfile1.h
    srcfile1.cpp
    ...
thirdpaty/
    Makefile.am
    lib1/
        Makefile.am
        lib1.h
        lib1.cpp
        ...
    lib2/
        ...
```

I use recursive Automake since some of the third party libraries are distributed with their own Automake files. `src/Makefile.am` includes the usual libtool macros:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylib.la 
libmylib_la_SOURCES = scrfile1.h srcfile1.cpp ...
```

How do I link the main library to the third party ones? The [Autotools manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Convenience-Libraries.html) leads me to believe that the third party libraries needs to be built as libtool convenience libraries, so I have the following in `thirdparty/lib1/Makefile.am`:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES  = libthirdpaty1.la
libthirdpaty1_la_SOURCES = lib1.cpp lib1.h
```

And add the following in `src/Makefile.am`:

```
libmylib_la_LIBADD = $(top_buildir)/thirdparty/lib1/libthirdpaty1.la
```

My root Makefile.am holds the INCLUDES macro:

```
INCLUDES = -I$(top_builddir)/thirdparty
```

But building with this configuration gives me undefined symbol errors.

What is the correct way to structure this source code and link all the libraries together?

Comment: What you're doing looks sane.  So I would start by looking at the symbols.  Are they defined?  If there are multiple convenience libraries, are they linked in the right order?  And so on.

Comment: You're right, I was including the subfolders in the wrong order. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that that source layout and libtool usage were fine, but my root Makefile.am had the following macro:

```
SUBDIRS = src thirdparty
```

Which should have been

```
SUBDIRS = thirdparty src
```

Since the code in `src/` referenced the code in `thirdparty/`, the `thirdparty/` code needed to be built first. The [`SUBDIRS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Subdirectories.html) macro causes subfolders to be built in the order they are specified, from left to right.